# How can I store a result in a variable in batch?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

For example, I have

```
find /C "Something" List.txt
```

And I want to store it in %a%

I think in bash is something like

```
var=`command`
```

But I don't know how...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method using a `for` loop:

```
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Find /C "Something"^<List.txt') Do "Set var=%%a"
```

And one using a temporary file:

```
Find /C "Something"<List.txt>tmp.tmp
Set/P "var="<"tmp.tmp"
```